# Create a Ubercart Drupal site to sell memberships?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I want to create a website to sell licenses (not software licenses).
Basically, these licenses are sold in the form of packages for, say, package of 1 license or package of 2 licenses.
If a user comes to the site and buys a package with `n` number of licenses then `n` number of Drupal users will be created.

The created users can have different role types to allow different content to be accessible for different users.

Is it possible to achieve that with some Drupal 7 modules?

I did some research and found that it is possible to sell roles/subscriptions using the *Ubercart* module but I don't know how to create users that way -- with different roles after buying license package(s).

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do this fairly recently.  Found a nice tutorial on Site Membership and Ubercart from Torontowebsitedeveloper.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbeqlNjBvwQ